# Excel VBA not recalculating sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA routine that substitutes certain values into cell "B16" (going off a list on a separate workbook), recalculates the entire workbook after each substitution and records the value of the cell "I31" (post recalculation) in another workbook.

The behaviour that I observe is a lot different from what I expect. Suppose that the value of "I31" is 0 before I run the routine and that it needs to be equal to 1 after the first iteration and equal to 2 after the second iteration. When I run the routine, both the recorded values are 0 (instead of 1 and 2) and the value of "I31" itself is 2. The latter makes sense. It seems like Excel is not refreshing the cell values before copying them into other cells. Maybe it is not waiting for 'SendKeys "{F9}"' to terminate before copying the cell values. So I forced the routine to pause for one minute after each iteration (the recalculation should take about ten seconds) and this time both the recorded values are 0 again and "I31" itself is also 0. This is even worse.

On a related note Application.Calculate (or its variants like Worksheet.Calculate) has no effect whatsoever on the worksheet. Nothing is being recalculated when I use those instead of SendKeys "{F9}". This occurs even if the only line in the routine is Application.Calculate. I have no clue why this is happening.

My routine is below. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub createData()

Dim x As Integer

For x = 1 To 2

    Range("B16").value = Worksheets("Types").Cells(x, 1)

    'Application.Calculate

    SendKeys "{F9}"

    'Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:01:00")

    Worksheets("Results").Cells(x, 1).value = Range("I31").value

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @Miqi180 The question states "Application.Calculate has no effect whatsoever on the worksheet"

Comment: What's in `Cells(x, 1)`? A UDF? Is it volatile? What's the calculation mode when the macro runs?

Comment: My guess is that your use of "Range("B16") without specifying which worksheet is the problem (i.e., Excel is using the B16 value from whichever sheet was last active). But, it would be a lot easier to help you if you'd include sample data, either through a screenshot, linked workbook, or just type it out. I'm not clear on how many total worksheets are involved.Also, you say that B16 gets its value "going off a list on a separate workbook"). I don't see a second workbook referenced in your code.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Cells(x, 1) is just an empty cell under the Results workbook. It is a string under the Types workbook that determines specifics of the calculation to be performed. I don't know what UDF, volatile or calculation mode means.

Comment: `Application.CalculateFull` may do what you want

Comment: Excel's calculation mode is `xlCalculationAutomatic`, until some code (or the user) toggles it otherwise (e.g. `xlCalculationManual`) - AFAIK calculation being manual is the only way Excel won't automatically recalculate when cells change, barring non-volatile user-defined functions. Research the terms if you're unsure what they are, but if you don't have VBA functions invoked by cells, you don't have UDF's to worry about.

Comment: Also you should be aware that `Range("...")` is implicitly referring to whatever worksheet is currently active, while `Worksheets("Results").Cells(...)` is explicitly qualifying the range with a specific worksheet object: assuming that's written in a standard module and not a worksheet's code-behind, your code will behave differently depending on what worksheet is active when it's invoked.

Comment: @SeanW333 Thanks for your suggestion. "B16" gets its values from the Types workbook. So there are three workbooks. The main one, Types and Results. The button attached to my macro is on the main one. It contains a ton of other stuff that I do not need to change but are essential for the calculations. I tried giving some dummy values in my question as an example but I am not sure if that is helpful.

Comment: Would help here to add a bit more information about exactly what types of calculations are being carried out - are they all basic worksheet formulas? (i.e. no custom VBA code)  Unless all your calculation inputs are part of the dependency tree that Excel creates when it calculates, results may not be what you expect

Comment: "there are three workbooks [...] the button is on the main one" - there it is: everything in this code is only ever interacting with whatever workbook is currently active, i.e. the one that has the button. Is it VBA code opening the 2 other workbooks? If so, please include that code too.

Comment: @TimWilliams It is a lot of custom VBA code and possibly custom Excel add-ins.

Comment: @TimWilliams I will give that a try. Thank you.

Comment: Wait did you mean "workbook", or "work*sheet*"? They're different, and conflating the two is confusing for everyone reading. The work*book* contains the work*sheets*.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you very much. I am not sure what you mean by "Is it VBA code opening the 2 other workbooks?". The workbooks are there. I am just accessing the values of the cells in Types and writing into the cells in Results, which start out as empty.

Comment: Ok it looks like you're confusing "workbook" with "worksheet". You don't have 3 workbooks, you have 3 worksheets, all in the same workbook. Correct?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I am very sorry. I meant worksheet. There is only one Excel file and it has three worksheets.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Correct.

Comment: What I meant was `Range("B16").Value` doesn't specify which worksheet B16 is on. Every time Excel encounters that line, the way it is written, Excel  is using the B16 of the last active sheet. Which may not be the sheet you intend. Specify the worksheet in that line and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: Also, there are no calculations in your code. What is being calculated, where, and by what method? ... You really need to post your workbook/worksheet data if you want anyone to be able to follow what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @SeanW333 pretty sure the calculation mishap is irrelevant - the data was just written to/from an unexpected cell

Comment: @SeanW333 The calculations are performed by some Excel add-in developed by a different team, which I will contact tomorrow. I have no clue what is going on in their code. I probably cannot post any part of it on public domain. I was hoping the issue I am having is independent of what is being done by this other code. But if the suggestions here don't help I may need to investigate deeper.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, I totally agree, as noted in my previous comments. Just trying to help the OP understand why their question is not clear and why people keep saying they need to see the work.

Comment: @Calculon, as others here have now noted, you shouldn't need to force the calculations, especially since it sounds like they take place somewhere else. Your problem is almost certainly in the way you are referencing the target cells in your code.

Comment: @SeanW333 I really hope that the problem is in my code. I will try your suggestion tomorrow. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit `ActiveSheet` references are the main problem, I think.

If the 3 sheets you're working with exist at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook` (i.e. they're not created at run-time, and you can see them in the VBE's *Project Explorer*), then locate them in the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), then bring up the *Properties* toolwindow (F4) and change their `(Name)` property (default would be e.g. `Sheet1`).

So you have a `TypesSheet` with a name "Types" - "Types" being the name on the sheet's "tab", and `TypesSheet` is an identifier you can use anywhere in the code to refer to that sheet.

Do the same for the other two, so you have `TypesSheet`, `ResultsSheet`, and `MainSheet`.

And now you can be both explicit and efficient:

```
TypesSheet.Range("B16").Value = TypesSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value
ResultsSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value = TypesSheet.Range("I31").Value
```

Not sure which specific sheets you meant to refer to, but this is unambiguous code that doesn't depend on what sheet is active when the macro starts running.

---

If the sheets are created at run-time (i.e. added to the workbook by some VBA code), then you can't use their *code name* and must dereference them from the `Worksheets` collection of a `Workbook` object.

If the sheets exist in `ThisWorkbook` (i.e. the same file where that VBA code is written in), then you can do this:

```
Dim typesSheet As Worksheet
Set typesSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Types")
```

And so on. Note that retrieving worksheet references by sheet name like this, makes your code vulnerable to a user that would rename the tabs (assuming an unprotected workbook structure). That's why you should use the code names whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your suggestions as well as others tomorrow and give an update.

Comment: I am afraid the macro behaves the same as before with your suggestions. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you assuming an automatic calculation mode by any chance? If calculation is manual, Excel won't calculate. Other than that, AFAICT the problem would not be in the code you supplied then.

Comment: I played with the calculation mode setting both via Excel menu and VBA. No changes occur. Pressing F9 in Excel results in some macros containing database queries being called. I don't know if this is some special case that requires a different treatment.

Comment: If you press F9 and VBA code runs, you're handling worksheet.calculate event, and/or have UDFs. If these functions involve the cells that aren't calculating, then make them volatile.